# Where to put extra GeoJson properties

Tags: d3.js, geojson, specifications

I'm creating a map for a country using GeoJson format but I'm wondering where to put extra country information such as `Name`, `Country Code` and some useful informations.

I know that we can easily do that for features (which in my case is regions data) but where can I put country properties ?

**us.json**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "REGION_ID": 1,
                "REGION_NAME": "My First Region",
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [1.83, 15.93]
                    ],
                    ...
                ]
            }
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: See also http://geojsonlint.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I insert this into [Mapbox geojsonhint](https://www.mapbox.com/geojsonhint/), it shows no errors:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "properties": {
        "name": "United states of America"  
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "REGION_ID": 1,
                "REGION_NAME": "My First Region"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [1.83, 15.93], [1.83, 15.93], [1.83, 15.93], [1.83, 15.93]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }

    ]
}
```